# How to open a file in filesystem: from a link

Tags: javascript, html5-filesystem

I have created a file using the FileSystem API. I can't open it from a simple link. However, I can open the page placing the URL manually in the browser (filesystem:http://localhost:8100/temporary/log.csv)

I'm testing only on google chrome for now.

```
window.open("filesystem:http://localhost:8100/temporary/log.csv")
```

I expect it to open in a new window.

UPDATE:
This issue was fixed by using window.URL.createObjectURL() 
so the link will be something like blob:http://localhost:8100/7aa5685c-ca4f-485a-8bf8-d1c95e6257ab which works

Comment: `"filesystem:http://localhost:8100/temporary/log.csv` makes no sense, `HTTP` is a network protocol and you request any server actions using it. If you want to read a file from the filesystem your server can do it (as long as the server is running on **your** local system) but your JS inside the browser (-> your webpage) may not access the local file system due to security issues.

Comment: Are you sure its working when you type it out in the URL field? Because i think it should be `file:///` not `filesystem:` to open local files (at least in chrome and firefox). What browser are you using?

Comment: The [FileSystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem) is non-standard, incompatible with a number of browsers, and is deprecated. You should avoid using it.

Comment: @messerbill the file is saved in the filesystem in the chrome. If I type filesystem:http://localhost:8100/temporary/log.csv in the browser I can see it the question is how can access it from a link. Thanks

Comment: @Olian04 I can access the file if I type filesystem:localhost:8100/temporary/log.csv in the browser

Answer (score 1):

If you know where in your filesystem is the root folder of your webserver (for example: `d:\apache\www_root\temporary\`) then copy your **csv** file to there.

Once its done, you should be able to open it from your Javascript by using:

`window.open("http://localhost:8100/temporary/log.csv")`

Comment: the file is in chrome filesystem but href="filesystem:http://localhost:8100/temporary/log.csv" doesn't behave like opening a page
filesystem:http://localhost:8100/temporary/log.csv
for reference : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#chrome-quirks

Answer (score 0):

Same issue.

Using FileSystem API since the product is Chrome only.

How did you turn the FileEntry into the objectURL?

Figured it out

```
// turn fileEntry to file
fileEntry.file((f) => {
    console.log(window.URL.createObjectURL(f));
});
```